# How to log data to the Flutter console?

Tags: intellij-idea, console, dart, flutter

I am a beginner and using IntelliJ IDEA, and I wanted to log data to the console?

I tried `print()` and `printDebug()`, but none of my data were showing in the Flutter console.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

If you're inside a Flutter `Widget`, you can use [`debugPrint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html), e.g.,

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

debugPrint('movieTitle: $movieTitle');
```

Or, use Dart's built in `log()` function

```
import 'dart:developer';

log('data: $data');
```

Comment: Is there any way where we can write  `array [0]`, `array[1]` or any run time assignment in the debugger ?

Comment: Note that debugPrint is now included in flutter/material so you don't necessarily need to import flutter/foundation.

Comment: Does debugPrint prints only one debug mode? In my app, I have lots of print statements which I use `print()` to print. What I want to do is to print only on debug mode.

Comment: Can an example using the `time` and `zone` param on `log()` be added please? How can one add those so it actually shows?

Comment: May I know which window in Android Studio shows the outputs of `log('blah')`? I don't see it in the `Run` tab.

Answer (score 38):

The Dart **print()** function outputs to the system console, which you can view using flutter logs (which is basically a wrapper around adb logcat).

If you output too much at once, then Android sometimes discards some log lines. To avoid this, you can use **debugPrint()**.

Found here: https://flutter.io/docs/testing/debugging

Answer (score 37):

log() from 'dart:developer'

- It doesn't seem to have a max length limits like `print()` or `debugPrint()`.
- So it comes helpful when you want to log the whole API response.
- And also helps in dart dev tools to show formatted logging.

```dart
import 'dart:developer';  //(auto import will do this even)
//example for api logging
  log("${response?.statusCode} :  ${response?.request?.path}",
          name: "Response", error: response.data);
```

Comment: It doesn't work or me in a web app.

Comment: I confim, log() doesn't work the same way on web. `error` and `stackTrace` are not printted if present

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, I have created a Logger for Flutter Apps: https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Flutter-Logger

Simply copy **`AppLog.dart`** & add to yor project and use it like this:

1. AppLog.i("Info Message");  // Simple Info message
2. AppLog.i("Home Page", tag: "User Logging"); // Info message with identifier TAG

**Examples:**

INPUT

```
    AppLog.v("-----------------------------");
    AppLog.d("I am Debug Log With Default TAG");
    AppLog.i("I am Info Log With Default TAG");
    AppLog.w("I am Warn Log With Default TAG");
    AppLog.e("I am Error Log With Default TAG");
    AppLog.wtf("I am Failure Log With Default TAG");
    AppLog.v("I am Verbose Log With Default TAG");

   //With TAGS
    AppLog.v("-----------------------------");
    AppLog.d("I am Debug Log With Custom TAG", tag: "Awesome Widget");
    AppLog.i("I am Info Log With Custom TAG", tag: "Awesome Widget");
    AppLog.w("I am Warn Log With Custom TAG", tag: "Awesome Widget");
    AppLog.e("I am Error Log With Custom TAG", tag: "Awesome Widget");
    AppLog.wtf("I am Failure Log With Custom TAG", tag: "Awesome Widget");
    AppLog.v("I am Verbose Log With Custom TAG", tag: "Awesome Widget");
    AppLog.v("-----------------------------");
```

OUTPUT:

> ```
> Restarted application in 347ms.
> FlutterApp: -----------------------------
> DEBUG|FlutterApp: I am Debug Log With Default TAG
> INFOⓘ|FlutterApp: I am Info Log With Default TAG
> WARN⚠️|FlutterApp: I am Warn Log With Default TAG
> ERROR⚠️|️FlutterApp: I am Error Log With Default TAG
> WTF¯\_(ツ)_/¯|FlutterApp: I am Failure Log With Default TAG
> FlutterApp: I am Verbose Log With Default TAG
> FlutterApp: -----------------------------
> DEBUG|Awesome Widget: I am Debug Log With Custom TAG
> INFOⓘ|Awesome Widget: I am Info Log With Custom TAG
> WARN⚠️|Awesome Widget: I am Warn Log With Custom TAG
> ERROR⚠️|️Awesome Widget: I am Error Log With Custom TAG
> WTF¯\_(ツ)_/¯|Awesome Widget: I am Failure Log With Custom TAG
> Awesome Widget: I am Verbose Log With Custom TAG
> FlutterApp: -----------------------------
> ```

**You can also set a filter for Log Levels**

> AppLog.setLogLevel(log_priority); // logs below log_priority will be hidden

Where priority is always:

> VERBOSE<=log_priority<= FAILURE

> Priority Level: VERBOSE<DEBUG<INFO<WARNING<ERROR<FAILURE

**Example**
Hide all info and Debug Logs:

```
AppLog.setLogLevel(AppLog.WARN);
AppLog.v("-----------------------------");
AppLog.d("Debug Log Will not be Visible");
AppLog.i("Info Log Will not be Visible");
AppLog.w("Warn Log Will be Visible");
AppLog.e("Error Log Will be Visible");
AppLog.wtf("Failure Log Will be Visible");
AppLog.v("Verbose Log  Will not be Visible");
AppLog.v("-----------------------------");
```

OUTPUT

> ```
> WARN⚠️|FlutterApp: Warn Log Will be Visible
> ERROR⚠️|️FlutterApp: Error Log Will be Visible
> WTF¯\_(ツ)_/¯|FlutterApp: Failure Log Will be Visible
> ```

Feel free to use my logger or if you have some ideas for improvement please create PR or let me know I will improve it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the package Logger :
https://pub.dev/packages/logger

This is the most used package for logging, and it clearly shows different levels of log in the console, with colors.

Answer (score 0):

I replace to print command to `logPrint`

In Android Studio debugging `Emulator.EMULATOR` equal "" I will see to the logs

In production or testing I will set it to a number

```
const bool debugMode = (Emulator.EMULATOR=="");
void logPrint(String _s) {
    if(debugMode){
        print(_s);
    }
}
class Emulator {
    static const EMULATOR = String.fromEnvironment('EMULATOR', defaultValue: "");
}
```