# How to print to log in Flutter?

Tags: android, debugging, flutter

I wanted to print a log statement onto any LogCat console (Verbose, Debug, etc) but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

The `print()` or `debugPrint()`  doesn't seem to work, or better yet should I say I don't know where they are printing.

Also, for some reason, the LogCat console is saying "No connected devices" and "No debuggable process" even though I have the emulator running in background and the files are executing on the emulator perfectly.

Comment: I have created a logger for flutter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68595809/2252113. feel free to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [Flutter Doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/logging), the logging view displays events from the Dart runtime, application frameworks (like Flutter), and application-level logging events.By default, the logging view shows:

- Garbage collection events from the Dart runtime
- Flutter framework events, like frame creation events
- `stdout` and `stderr` from applications
- Custom logging events from applications

Refer the [Debugging Flutter Applications Programmatically](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging#logging) Doc.
You can use:

```
stderr.writeln('print me');
```

Or

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

void main() {
  developer.log('log me', name: 'my.app.category');

  developer.log('log me 1', name: 'my.other.category');
  developer.log('log me 2', name: 'my.other.category');
}
```

Or

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

void main() {
  var myCustomObject = ...;

  developer.log(
    'log me',
    name: 'my.app.category',
    error: jsonEncode(myCustomObject),
  );
}
```

to log from your app.