# I got error while using "print" keyword in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The function 'print' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'print', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'print'.

Comment: Show us the code which reproduces this problem.

Comment: @julemand101 Here's the code :  if (event.status == Status.ERROR) {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
          print("Oops! Error");
          });
        }

Comment: Try with  restarting your IDE,

Comment: could you use debugPrint() inside your widget instead, or the predefined dart function log(). look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940719/how-to-log-data-to-the-flutter-console

Answer (score 0):

Dart is case sensitive
you will get this kind of error as a result of the wrong use of the case
Check if you use Capital letters for the 'print' statement
like "Print")