# Flutter developer log command doesn't print on the command line

Tags: flutter, dart, logging, mobile

I cannot print with the log command at all. Print command works perfect.

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

void main() {
  developer.log('log me', name: 'my.app.category');
  print('i am a print');
  developer.log('log me 1', name: 'my.other.category');
  developer.log('log me 2', name: 'my.other.category');
}
```

in this example i only see `i am a print`

Recently i upgraded Flutter on my machine. this is the `flutter --version`

```
Flutter 3.19.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision bae5e49bc2 (4 days ago) • 2024-02-13 17:46:18 -0800
Engine • revision 04817c99c9
Tools • Dart 3.3.0 • DevTools 2.31.1
```

I have other projects of application but like magic there they work. Now the ones that i created with the new flutter they do not work. Please help me

I tried upgrading the flutter to last version nothing.
I tried running on emulator and real device no difference.
I tried using just dart on a single file but no difference from run a flutter application.
I don't want to use the logger package. I want to use chopper who uses log command so i cannot skip the problem by just ignoring it. So for the logger package is not a solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log data to the Flutter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940719/how-to-log-data-to-the-flutter-console)