# Android Studio not showing Logcat with Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, logcat

I'm using Android Studio for **Flutter** App Development. Everything seems to be working fine just that the Android Studio does not show the "logs" in Logcat. In the Logcat section, it says "Please Configure Android SDK". Which is already configured. And in the Logcat section says "No Connected Devices." in the drop-down menu. When it has recognized my Android Phone and is showing it just under the Menu bar.

Is there a fix for it? Is there something I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update April 2020:** [Cuong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007784/android-studio-not-showing-logcat-with-flutter#53844409) works better with Android Studio 3.6+

---

Previous answer:

**Flutter** use Run tab to display logs in Android Studio. Switch from Logcat to Run and then you will see logs.

Comment: This is absurd. The Logcat provides powerful tools for filtering logs, which the Run dialog doesn't.

Comment: This is not useful if we want to check logs when app is stopped.

Comment: This is not answering the question. Correct answer is below https://stackoverflow.com/a/60619362/2760919

Comment: This does not work if you installed app via adb install

Answer (score 73):

Try the following:

- `Event Log` (*a tab at the bottom right*)
  [image]
- scroll to `Android framework is detected`

[image]

- click [Configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60619362/3290339)

The `Logcat` tab should appear now. Moreover, the `Device File Explorer` tab should show up on the right panel.

Answer (score 44):

I just solved this, the flutter project was missing an Android module. Go to 'File -> Project Structure -> Modules'. Click on the '+' sign at the top to add a module. Select Android.

Comment: This worked after I selected android SDK in project structure.

Comment: Having the latest Android Studio, this seems to be the correct answer! Thank you

Answer (score 24):

Go to Setting/Preferences -> Languages & Framework -> Flutter ->
Check or uncheck **Replace the Run and Debug console  with an experimental Flutter Loggin view**

Comment: Thank you! This should be the accepted answer. That log view is so much more readable than the regular text.

Comment: I don't see that option on that screen.

Comment: Option missing now (using Flutter 1.12.13)

Comment: Please check the other (correct) answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60619362/2760919

Answer (score 12):

Just open another NATIVE project for Android Studio in other window and the logcat will work, do it while Flutter project is open. That was the solution for me

Answer (score 9):

Find a way around it (macOS).

Go to Project Structure -> Facets -> "+" -> Android -> Select Project.

Logcat should now be visible. Configure Android SDK if not done previously and you should be able to use Logcat.

Reference https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2724

Answer (score 8):

*When I first came to Flutter from an Android background, I didn't know where to find the log statements. I didn't care so much about all of the system messages. I just wanted to see log messages from my app during development. This answer is for people like that, not for people who specifically need LogCat itself.*

In Flutter apps you can log text using the `print()` statement.

```
print('hello');
```

As others have said, you can use the Run tab in Android Studio to view these logged comments.

[image]

Here is the code for main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Button'),
        onPressed: () {
          print('hello'); //               <-- logging
        },
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: when i try to search specific word it shows The view is read only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299666/unable-to-search-logs-in-android-studio?noredirect=1#comment131173677_74299666

Answer (score 8):

Open Project Stucture -> Modules -> new **android** module from exists source.

Logcat & Device File Explorer will be visible.

for Android Studio 3.6:
File -> New -> New Module -> Android Library

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue:
`I have done the following steps to resolved it:`

- Click the event log on the bottom right of android studio
  [image]
- Click on configure [image]
- Click on Ok in the dialog box

[image]

- Logcat will be available now[image]

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's an ADB issue. You can restart AS (or maybe even your Computer) or what i usually do is open the terminal an then: `adb kill-server && adb start-server` (I think the second part `adb start-server` is not necessary because it seems that AS handles it automatically) - anyways this is how LogCat and Android (and Flutter) work for me every time.

Answer (score 3):

### 1.

Go to Menu and select 'Project Structure' -> 'Project'

[image]

### 2.

In 'Project Structure' Select Project SDK

[image]

**And just now click on OK and Apply.**

Comment: It's NOT working (showing the Logcat panel)

Comment: @us_david just restart AndroidStudio after changes.

Answer (score 2):

Just use command 'flutter logs', then you can see all logs which are printed by 'print' or 'debugPrint' function.

Answer (score 2):

When i face this problem I just go to `File` and open my existing native `android project` and then close it. This solution also works when `abd Wifi pludings` does show warning like => adb not found.

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
adb logcat
```

and watch from terminal.
Doc: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Answer (score 1):

when you open flutter project, IDE prompts you to configure android project. Just click on the recommendation and it will start showing logcat window.

Answer (score 1):

In case you accidentally refused to configure Android framework and now struggling to find the LogCat window. Then delete .idea, .dart_tool and .gradle folders in project root and android folder. Then Invalidate and restart. It will ask to configure detected Android framework. Click 'configure'.

Answer (score 1):

In new versions of Android Studio, after deploying the app to device/emulator, in **Run** Tab you will see an option for flutter dev tools as shown in the image, it will open in browser (based on default chrome/edge) and there you can see logcat/logging

[image: Android Studion artic for run tab]

Flutter Dev Tools

[image: Flutter Dev Tools in Google Chrome]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1`

1- From project tab, make sure you are in project view from top.

2- Right click on your project top folder (with flutter icon)

3- Go to `Flutter -> Open Android module in Android Studio`

4- Wait for indexing, and then you can use logcat in both windows, so you can close the android module.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the “Run” tab to see the logs and if you want to insert logs (like `Log.d()` in android), you can use `print()` function and whatever string you pass into it will be printed into the **“Run”** window.

Comment: Whenever i search something it shows The view is read only

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution worked for me:

for MacOS:
Go to: /Users/userName/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.4/options
Find "runner.layout.xml"
Change the name of this file for ex: runner01.layout.xml
Restart Android studio

for Windows:
1- Focus "Run" tab (click on tab header, not on its body)
2- Ctrl+Shift+A, find and click "Restore Layout"

References:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25835
https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3673#issuecomment-517356243

Hopefully, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also had an error in the Device File Explorer: `Error initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge no found`.
I fixed the problem following [Error initializing ADB: Debug Bridge not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291708/error-initializing-adb-debug-bridge-not-found): I selected the latest Android API Platform as Project SDK in File/Project Structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to **File** => **Project Structure** => and in the “**SDK project**” choose “**Android**”

Answer (score 0):

1. close project
2. delete .dart_tool,.idea,build files
3. start android studio,logcat will display

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `File > Project Structure` Project or use <kbd>cmd</kbd>  + <kbd>;</kbd> or
2. Then click on "Facets" and press <kbd>+</kbd> icon in the upper right corner and add `Android` from the list.

   [image]

Credit to [@MrWeeMan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68374488/12483095)

Answer (score 0):

Some times for some reasons like `flutter clean` or changing in files directory, android studio usually excludes some files from project modules. here is some simple steps to help you solve the problem:

go to  `File` --> `Project Structure` --> `Modules`

There are **2** common scenarios.

- Android studio might have **completely removed** your project from modules. For this you need to add it again using steps shown in the picture below.

Click on the plus icon and the add your project here. Then press Apply and lastly OK.

[image]

- Android studio just **excluded some of the files and folders** from your flutter project. In the right panel you can see them in red. just remove them from exclude list and again Apply and OK.

[image]

**NOTE: In both scenarios you need to stop the project and rerun it. or better close and reopen android studio**

Answer (score 0):

In Mac
Go to File -> Project Structure -> Facets -> “+” -> Android -> Select Project
Then Click on Apply button Logcat should be visible now but it will showing please configure Android SDK like this

[image]

Click on **configure** As you can see Module SDK is not selected we need to select it.

[image]

Select Android API 32 Platform then click Ok button!

[image]

**Now your logcat will work!**

Answer (score 0):

Logcat was showing "Could not detect project package names. Is the project synced?" The only filter was `package:mine`. After replacing it with `package:<my_apps_packagename>`, Logcat showed normally. I think this issue is common if you switch between Android and Flutter projects.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable verbose logging for flutter if you are looking for AppId or something of that sort.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

**Flutter** has not logcat flutter show error in the console inside Run tab.IF you want to see error and crash report click on run tab.