# Flutter android studio in mac showing Please configure Android SDK in Logcat

Tags: macos, flutter, android-studio-3.0

I'm using mac os Mojave and android studio for flutter. whenever I create a new Flutter project in the android studio, it is showing that please configure Android SDK. Android SDK is already configured and flutter doctor checked it successfully. I invalidate the cache and restarted the android studio but nothing worked for me. I configured flutter using official flutter website

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio not showing Logcat with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007784/android-studio-not-showing-logcat-with-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution as follows :

1. Open a Flutter project in Android Studio.
2. Click on <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Project Structure</kbd>.
3. Select the <kbd>Project</kbd> tab, under <kbd>Project Settings</kbd>.
4. At the main screen, we should see No SDK in red under the Project SDK section.
5. Click on the dropdown menu and select an API version installed. Example: Android API 30 platform.
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
7. Restart Android Studio (I prefer to restart your mac)