# Error initializing ADB: Debug Bridge not found

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I want to work with some files in flutter and so I wanted to use the Android Studio Device File Explorer to check if everything works correctly. 
But the Device File Explorer shows a red warning "Error initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found"

On a "normal" Android Project with Java there is no Problem and everything is displayed correctly.

I reinstalled Android Studio, changed the AVD but nothing changed.

Is this a bug in Flutter or Android Studio?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: You might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345049/10576762) helpful

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my problem is, that this problem only occurs in Flutter projects and not in Java Android Projects

Comment: Are you using an emulator?

Comment: Yes, I am using an emulator but the problem is solved. But still, thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. You must go to your Project Structure, add a Project SDK to your project and reopen Android Studio. Then the Problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The error might occur when you create a Flutter app in VS Code instead of Android Studio. To fix it, simply add a `misc.xml` file in your `.idea` folder, with the following contents or similar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_12" default="false" project-jdk-name="Android API 29 Platform" project-jdk-type="Android SDK" />
  <component name="ProjectType">
    <option name="id" value="io.flutter" />
  </component>
</project>
```

You could also create a new Flutter project in Android Studio to view the contents of `misc.xml` as it might differ slightly.