# "Please configure Android SDK" error show up after adding Facebook login in flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, facebook-login, android-sdk-manager

I am developing a flutter application which use firebase and Facebook login.

My app is working perfectly after adding firebase authentication. But after I add Facebook login I can no longer build the project. The console show 'Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1'.

When I check the logcat, it tells me to "Please configure android SDK".

When I click it, the below image show up

[image: android sdk configuration]

This is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutter_bloc_test_project">

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="flutter_bloc_test_project"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

I have tried method like Downgrading gradle version. But the firebase won't work with low version that's why I had to upgrade in the first place.

Please help

Comment: Please configure Android SD<== to resolve this error I generally open a native android project.

Comment: See this [Android Studio not showing Logcat with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007784/android-studio-not-showing-logcat-with-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue could be that the recently added plugins might not have been established as expected. What you can do here is run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to rebuild the added packages.

If the issue persists, the issue might be caused by the Flutter plugin configured in Android Studio. Try running `File > Invalidate Caches...` and restart Android Studio to refresh the config set.