# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I am repeatedly getting this error again and again despite trying everything I could find online.
So far I have done these steps to solve this problem:

1. Removed android stuido, intelliJ and flutter and installed all of it again.
2. Reinstalled all SDK packages several times, i have attached image of all SDK packages for refernece.[Please have a look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efGUx.jpg)
3. Accepted all licenses.

> ```
>  C:\Users\Asus>flutter doctor --android-licenses
> All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
>
>
> C:\Users\Asus>flutter doctor
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836], locale en-IN)
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0-rc4)
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
>
> • No issues found!
> ```

4. Tried using earlier version of flutter and tried again after upgrading it.

After doing all this I am still getting this error for all projects. Even the basic project which is pre-written when creating a new flutter project.

> 

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! We need some more info for the gradle failure: do the logs contain anything in that regard?

Comment: @AlexTimonin, Logcat shows 'PLEASE CONFIGURE ANDROID SDK'

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51007784/1117696)

Comment: tried using invalidate cache and restart option. Still getting the same error

Comment: How about [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16691)?

Comment: So when emulator is connected it shows a bunch of logs but I think they are just processes running on the emulator. When emulator is nor running it shows nothing. However the same error stills shows up while running the main.dart