# Failing to get debug app check token for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-app-check

I'm closely following app check documentation in order to use debug token, however instead of seeing it logged out in the console I see following error (when running in debug simulator from xcode)

EDIT: Everything works as expected in testflight / real device build

EDIT 2: Created related [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9547)

```
[Firebase/AppCheck][I-FAA004002] Failed to exchange debug token to app check token: Error Domain=com.firebase.appCheck Code=0 "The server responded with an error: 
 - URL: https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/[my-project-id]/apps/1:[sensitive-data]:ios:[sensitive-data]:exchangeDebugToken 
 - HTTP status code: 403 
 - Response body: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "App attestation failed.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

**Thus far I've implemented following steps, but had no luck**

1. Enabled both attestation providers for my ios project (App Attest got enabled automatically when I added my team id)
   [image]

---

2. Added `FIRAppCheckDebugProviderFactory` in my code i.e.

```objectivec
  #if DEBUG
    FIRAppCheckDebugProviderFactory *providerFactory = [[FIRAppCheckDebugProviderFactory alloc] init];
    [FIRAppCheck setAppCheckProviderFactory:providerFactory];
  #endif
  
  [FIRApp configure];
```

---

3. Added `-FIRDebugEnabled` to my debug run launch arguments in schema
   [image]

---

4. Added AppCheck capability to my target and set .entitlements App Attest environment to production
   [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was resolved upstream via addition to documentation
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9547#issuecomment-1097424478

In short

1. The very first time app is installed / started it logs debug token
2. Once debug token is logged it should be added in firebase dashboard
3. After this all subsequent launches of the app reuse debug token that was logged initially
4. If initial token was not added to firebase console a 403 error will be thrown as app is using unverified token

Comment: What should I do if I don't see the debug token after running "flutter run" for iOS from the console?
Maybe I missed it the first time. Can I show the debug token again later?

Answer (score 2):

You must also enable Manage Debug Tokens
, this link and pic can help you:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider?authuser=0&hl=en

[image]

[image]

Comment: Issue is that I never get the debug token that needs to be pasted into this view i.e. no "SDK log message" happens due to error above

Comment: @Ilja maybe the link helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68299859/can-not-generate-a-debug-token-for-firebase-storage-with-app-check

Comment: Tried re-downloading my info plist file (iOS), but there is no change there. Will keep trying. thank you for your suggestions by the way

Comment: i already got the debug token , and after that already added also to firebase app check console . Do we send the debug token to the backend also ? i tried to send token through header 'X-Firebase-AppCheck' it keeps saying it's invalid . kindly help