# Cannot generate a debug token with App Check via Firebase for Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-app-check

This is similar to [a different stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68299859/can-not-generate-a-debug-token-for-firebase-storage-with-app-check), but there wasn't an accepted answer and mine is for flutter instead.

I need a debug token for my Flutter app. I am following [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider) from the Firebase documentation. When I get to step 3, my debug token doesn't print out like it says in the documentation.

This is what I expected:

[image: Expected]

I have tried going through the instructions again but have not had success. Does the debug token only show up once and did I miss it? If so, how could I regenerate one? Is there something else that I missed?

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.