# Unable to search Logs in Flutter Run Tab using Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, debugging

I am working on flutter app using android studio. I want to print different statements using `print` and `debugprint`
i.e

```
debugPrint('Containter is tapped');
```

I am unable to search my `print` statements log in android studio, whenever I try `ctrl + F` and paste the specific line I want to search, it shows **The View is Read Only**

Here is the image of what I am trying and message android studio throw

[image: DetailedImage]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio not showing Logcat with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007784/android-studio-not-showing-logcat-with-flutter)

Comment: I tried all of them but did not work